# Inferring Subclasses from Property Restrictions

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, reasoner

I am trying to understand the cases where OWL classes "overlap" based on existential property restrictions.

### No Intersection

Here there's no overlap in the number of `name` properties each class has, so there can be no individuals that belong to both classes. The reasoner therefore infers their intersection to be unsatisfiable (equivalent to owl:Nothing).

```
# Declared
DataProperty: name

Class: A
    SubClassOf: 
        name max 1 xsd:string

Class: B
    SubClassOf: 
        name min 2 xsd:string

# Inferred (pseudocode)
(A and B)
    EquivalentTo:
        owl:Nothing
```

### Proper Subclass

Here the restriction of one class completely includes the other's, so I would've thought the individuals of `Person1` would be implied to belong to `Person2`, and the reasoner would infer A is a subclass of B or infer that the class (A and not B) is unsatisfiable, but this does not happen. **I'm looking for an explanation of why this is the case.** Thanks!

```
# Declared
DataProperty: name

Class: A
    SubClassOf: 
        name exactly 2 xsd:string

Class: B
    SubClassOf: 
        name min 2 xsd:string

# Nothing Inferred
```

Comment: `SubClassOf` axioms provide necessary conditions for belonging to a class, but not sufficient ones. All you know is that i) `B` is in (at least or evens equals, but we don't know) a larger set `S1` defined by the class expression `name min 2 xsd:string` and ii) `A` is in a subset `S2` defined by `name exactly 2 xsd:string` of that larger set `S1`

Comment: but how would you know if the set of individuals of `B` would be in `A`? That can't be decided here. Take a sheet of paper and visualize the 4 sets with circles, you'll see that you can never make the decision to put the circle for `A` inside `B` with any evidence, right? I mean, it could be the case that `A` is in `B` or they overlap or they just exist besides each other, but we never know

Comment: If you make both axioms `EquivalentTo` instead of `SubClassOf` that would indeed work.